# Detecting UserControl User Custom Cursor, and Getting Callbacks

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, kinect

I am creating a fullscreen demo application (demo = not production, so hacky code is okay though not preferred) for the Kinect SDK.  The application hides the Windows cursor and shows a custom hand cursor which is defined as a  object.

What I would like to do is create a custom UserControl (let's call it "HoverControl") that can detect when the cursor object is over it and then send back timer ticks, allowing the cursor object to update in some way (showing the user that something is about to happen).

The behavior is pretty much a copy of the Xbox 360 Kinect behavior.  How things look will just be a little different.

How can I detect with the cursor  object is over a "HoverControl" and have receive a callback from the HoverControl?

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

**CLARIFICATION:**
I am not currently moving the Windows cursor, so MouseEnter doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coding my own cursor in XAML, and creating a UserControl out of it, I set up a timer inside the control to perform a hit test for certain buttons (again, their own unique UserControl type) around my interface.

I ran into one issue with the hit test, which I was ultimately able to solve and detail in the following post at MSDN:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a8cdb265-21cc-4fd0-b40d-e6778b659852

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own cursor by making one using [Online Cursor Maker](http://www.rw-designer.com/online-cursor-editor). See [this website](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors) on how to set it. Then you can use `MouseEnter` and/or `MouseLeave`.